# Repetation of column when using join between two table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, duplicates, rows

As per using select query in postgres along 8 or 9 table using join found output as

```
 1. A    2   34
 2. A    2   56
 3. B    3   34
 4. B    3   56
```

whereas i required output in two form either

```
 1. A    2   34
 2. A    2   34
 3. B    3   56
 4. B    3   56
```

or

```
    A    2   34
    B    3  56
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct?

```
select distinct * from table
```

Comment: select distinct l.loacl_end_pop_address,l.numbers_line,m.total_bandwidth from new_reg_proposal_connectivity_dtl_at_pop l left join  new_reg_proposal_connectivity_to_pop m  on l.temp_reg_no=m.temp_reg_no where l.temp_reg_no='ABC'